# Controller not found in prestashop

Tags: controller, admin, prestashop

Getting Error in prestashop admin section. The admin controller for module is not found and showing the error "Controller not found".

Comment: Did you set something in the "menus" section of the admin before that happened?

Comment: No I was creating a module without any menus at backend.

Answer (score 1):

I've only got some experience with Prestashop 1.6 so maybe this is different for 1.5, but following the flow of the code it seems that you MUST have a tab (a main menu item) that links to your module.

So, if your module is called MyModule and the controller is called AdminMyModuleController, then you must add a menu item through administration->menu's and add:

**Name**: My Module

**Class**: AdminMyModule (Without "Controller" behind it)

**Module**: mymodule *(just like the directory name of your module)*

If that menu item (tab) is not there you just keep getting an error.

Maybe this Prestashop forum post will give some more answers soon: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/465996-modules-and-multiple-admin-controllers/

Answer (score 0):

```
If it shows the error after logged in to admin panel
then check 
does this file /controllers/admin/AdminDasboard.php
exist in your prestashop installation?

if yes

put this  code before last line in admin/index.php


if (!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['tab']))
{
$_GET['controller']='AdminDashboard';
}
```